# How to list all products wp-restapi wrapper java v1.2?

Tags: java

the method getAll do not return all the items, only 10 ..

```
List products = wooCommerce.getAll(EndpointBaseType.PRODUCTS.getValue());
```

How to get all products ? In other way, how to update items with "sku" key ?

Comment: Please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

This should be moved to wooCommerce question. It doesn't look like a java related one.